# How to address leaving during probationary period?

Tags: job-change

I am going to complete 6 months probationary period next month at my current job.
During this probationary period, my notice period is 15 days. After completing my probationary period, my notice period increases to 2 months.

I'm unhappy with my current position as I'm not able to meet my financial commitments and am looking for a better paid position.

I'm worried that leaving my current role, especially during the probationary period will look bad on my CV and to potential interviewers.

How can I best address this when applying and interviewing for another role?

Comment: Just as an advice... best to use a term other than "probation". I thought you've been convicted and released, that sort of thing.

Comment: @HK-51 "Probation" is the technical and correct term.

Comment: What is your country? Rules and expectations for terminating a probationary period vary per country.

Comment: "I'm worried that leaving my current role, especially during the probationary period will look bad on my CV and to potential interviewers." - Determining if a company is a good or if you are a good fit for the company is the entire point of the probationary period.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can quitting during probation be viewed as negative by future employers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/102054/can-quitting-during-probation-be-viewed-as-negative-by-future-employers)

Answer (score 4):

> But i don't know what to tell as reason for job change during interview?

Quitting during notice does make a lot of sense, so there isn't much to explain about the timing.

However, you need to explain the reason. "More money" is acceptable but not great. You will have to explain :

1. Why did you take the job in the first place. You knew the compensation when you signed on. Why did you accept it, if it's not enough?
2. Will you do the same thing to your new employer in 6 months? What is different this time around so this won't happen again?

Interviewing and hiring takes a lot of effort, time and money. Most employers are looking for hires that are long term sustainable for both parties. You need to credibly explain why this is a good fit for you.

Comment: Cheat sheet: (1) he accepted the offer because he has to work, and there was no better offer at the time - now there is a better prospect to consider. (2) what's different this time around is better starting pay, and therefore less need to seek more pay, and lower likelihood of another higher pay offer occuring even if sought. (end). Employers always claim to be looking for "long-term hires" - if they are serious about it, then they have to be serious about sustaining market-leading pay for the long-term (oops, I said the quiet part out loud!).

Comment: This may or may not work, There is a difference between "sustainable" and "chasing every extra $20" I've hired enough people to know the difference and I have never paid anyone "below market"

Comment: Well obviously the rise has to be credible, if the stated reason for leaving is pay. But bear in mind that someone willing to move for a relatively modest (but nevertheless real) rise, might also be moving due to additional dissatisfaction with poor conditions or working environment, which are often concomitant with poor pay.

Answer (score 2):

I'm of the same view as @Ertai87. If you're changing jobs for more money, then simply saying so will wash fine with most employers.

Only a foolish employer - or a true bottom feeder - would take umbrage at the idea that they are attracting candidates by offering more pay than their competitors.

Be prepared however for follow-up questions. For example, why your current employer will not raise your pay, and why you are valuable at the higher level of pay you are now seeking.

Again, I've found it washes fine to simply say the current employer "cannot afford an increase" (this is code for stinginess), and that the higher level sought is a more normal level of pay for someone of your background/responsibility/skill.

Comment: The problem with this, and which I addressed in my answer, is that this raises the question in that interviewer's head: "will this person up and leave my company in 2-3 months if they find someone else who will pay them more money?  If so, why should I spend my time and resources (of which it takes a lot) to hire and onboard this person?"  My answer resolves this issue by saying, it's not that OP simply wants more money, but he wants enough to pay his bills and then he'll be satisfied and not move jobs again.

Comment: @Ertai87, but the obvious answer to your question is "of course!". The willingness of new employees to leave your organisation after a short while for another significantly better pay offer, won't depend much on whether their previous employment was 3 months or 10 years.

Comment: That depends on your definition of "significant".

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to remember with a Probationary period is that it's a two-way street.

The company is assessing whether or not you are right for the role *and you are likewise assessing if the company is right for you*.

If you live in a culture where it is seen as rude or a faux pas to specifically state that you are leaving your current position due to wanting more money - then here is how I would address it:

"During the Probationary period, the role was not what I expected, the support structures were not in place, I was not getting the mentoring and advancement I wanted and the overall I didn't feel that the company and it's structure was the right fit for me"

There's nothing wrong with rejecting a company during a probationary period as an employee.

Comment: even better if you pick up on something the company you are interviewing with prides itself on (usually a read of their website will tell you if they are big on mentoring/training/teamwork/work environment....) and say you felt old company lacked that. Maybe mention the pay thing as a secondary concern.

Comment: If the reason is "wanting more money", that would raise the question for me, why did the OP accept the contract at all. Leaving for wanting more money after a few years makes sense, leaving during a probationary period much less so (or at least, it gives a bad impression).

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with "the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth, so help me God"?

> My current company is not paying me a salary that is able to keep up with my financial obligations.  I need a better salary to continue to pay my financial commitments.

There's a meaningful difference (or at least I would expect there to be) between "I'm a job hopper and I just want to make as much money as I can so I'm going to change jobs every 3 months to get a raise" and "my company isn't paying me a decent enough wage to be able to live on so I need more money to pay my bills".  You seem to be the latter, so just say so.

Comment: *"There's a meaningful difference..."* - is there? If you can change jobs every 3 months for a payrise - a meaningful one, I mean - then you're simply not being paid enough to begin with.

Comment: @Steve That's not how employers see it, and how employers see it is the most important thing when you're job hunting.  Even if you're right (and you are), the fact of the matter is that if the company that OP is interviewing with thinks that OP is going to change jobs in 3 months for a new salary, then OP isn't going to get hired anywhere and he's going to be stuck at his current company with a low salary.  He has to say he wants a higher salary while also dispelling the idea that he's simply greedy.

Comment: The only employers who think you're "greedy" for *seeking the pay they are offering* clearly have some sort of mental defect. Many employers will appreciate direct and credible answers that chime with their real-world understandings - "I'm here because your pay offer is extremely attractive and appreciably better than the job I've not long started" - and I wouldn't advise a candidate to prevaricate on the facts of their situation, based simply on how some oddball employers may interpret it.